# what are the other ways to fetch data from mysql than Mysqli_fetch_array();

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been working on a project and I wanted to try something new to fetch data from MySQL. I am looking to get data to the project other than using

`mysql_fetch_assoc()`

If there can be any other way please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by something new, same concept, new methods etc?

Comment: without using traditional ways.

Comment: I would then suggest to go for PDO, build a database class and do all your data calls to this class. See example in answers below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysqli_fetch_all()` which fetches all result rows and returns the result-set as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.

```
mysqli_fetch_all(result, resulttype)
```